# j_spring_security_check Throwing 302 and redirecting

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application which is configured using Spring but when I login (post).
The spring_security_check is throwing 302 and getting redirect to get.

I googled internet and could you see lots of folks complaining about this and could not find a proper solution for this, As it is doing a redirection to get, my J_user_name and j_password is getting exposed.

The 302 is happening for logout also, Not sure whether this is a duplicate query but could not find any proper explanations.

Any thoughts why spring security throws 302?

```
   <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/welcome"  authentication-failure-url="/failedLogin"/>
<logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/bye" />
```

Comment: Any particular web server?

Comment: Debug your app and find out where the redirect comes from. You can do this easily by adding a filter to your `web.xml` which creates an `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and dumps the stack when redirect is called on the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the attributes for :

```
<form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/library"
        authentication-failure-url="/failedLogin"
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
 />
```

Check that you have action in your custom form jsp the same as in "login-processing-url".